# AJAX request over http defaulting to https

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

I'm trying to make an AJAX POST request from a Chrome extension to an AWS app I have running.  The request itself is specified over http (as opposed to https) and I thought I had added the proper CORS headers to my AWS app (below):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  next();
});
```

However, the POST request times out from the extension, with the simple error "connection timed out."  How can I fix this?

Comment: check from a postman or a fiddler request to see if you can hit the url. also if CORS is enabled, then you should see two requests made, an OPTIONS request followed by the actual POST request. If the options request is coming back with the valid headers, then it could be that you are blocking and not returning

Comment: The request works via http with curl, but not via https (timeout).  I'll check postman right now.

Comment: so http://<your api> works but call to https://<you api> doesnt?

Comment: exactly, and the AJAX POST request I guess defaults to https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it works with HTTP and not over HTTPS, are you sure you opened the HTTPS port you are using in the security groups inbound rules?
[Inbound rules HTTP example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pisal.png)

And also check that you have HTTPS permissions in your manifest file:

```
"permissions": ["https://*/*",    "http://*/*"],
```

Comment: What `manifest file` are you talking about?  I added the inbound HTTPS rules, and now I get a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED instead of a timeout.  I think I may need to follow this guide (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html) which involves adding HTTPS listeners to load balancers.

Comment: I was talking about the manifest file of the Chrome Extension. Now that you have added the inbound HTTPS rules, it is good to see that the error has changed ! Indeed now you may need to search more on how to configure HTTPS on your application, not from Chrome Extension side.